# using exec how to save variable equal to a string

Tags: python, python-exec

I am using exec to save a variable equal to a string.  I am getting a SyntaxError. I'm assuming exec is getting confused with the value as string. Is this assumption accurate? Would appreciate the learnings! If I changed each question to an str(int), the code will work. Any help is much appreciated.

```
json_template = {
    "Introduction" : {
        "What is your Department?" : "",
        "What is your Name?" : "",
        "What is your Email?" : ""
    },
    "Context" : {
        "What is the necessary action or change?": "",
        "What is the urgency?" : "",
        "What lead to this change?" : "",
        "What is the opportunity or pain point this action solves?" : ""
    }
}

for each_category in json_template:
    for index, each_question in enumerate(json_template[each_category]):
        left_side = each_category + str(index)
        right_side = each_question

        bigstring = '='.join([left_side, right_side])

        exec(bigstring)
        print(bigstring)
```

Error below:

> ```
> exec(bigstring)   
> File "<string>", line 1
> Introduction0=What is your Department?
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: You need quotes around the RHS

Comment: What exactly is the RHS?

Comment: The right-hand side of an assignment expression.

Comment: As an aside, you almost certainly want to use dictionaries instead of global variables with computed values. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: What is the desired behaviour of calling `exec(bigstring)` here exactly?

Comment: Thank you @snakecharmerb needed quotes around RHS!

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure, what you are trying to achieve, but I do not think the problem is in string:
As you can see from link below: [exec info](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec)

"The exec() method executes a dynamically created program, which is either a string or a code object.".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).